# Twitter Timelines in EE

Tags: add-on

I noticed that EllisLab recently deprecated their Twitter-Timeline plugin due to Twitter's retirement of the API it uses:

https://github.com/EllisLab/Twitter-Timeline/

Has anyone been able to use any of the Twitter-related add-ons at Devot:ee to achieve the same effect? If anyone has any suggestions in this area (regarding embedding Twitter timelines in EE page templates), I would be glad to hear them. Similarly, any information about whether an updated version of the EllisLab original plugin is in the works would also be quite welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [CE Tweet](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-tweet) by [Causing Effect](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-tweet). I'm not really certain all Twitter Timeline did, but CE Tweet uses Twitter's new API v 1.1, OAuth, and has a number of great features.

We primarily use it to bring a clients tweets directly into ExpressionEngine, so we can display however needed. I believe you can also use it to post to Twitter. It was pretty easy to set-up, but make sure you follow the instructions carefully. The various keys you need to create are important.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

CE Tweet looks like it will be a great fit for what this particular client has in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen this listing: [Twitter API v1.1 add-ons](http://www.janinedalton.com/blog/archives/2013/expressionengine-twitter-api-v1-1-add-ons/)?

Comment: Thank you, Lisa. I had not seen that one, but it's good to know that EE Twitter is also available. I think this client may prefer CE Tweet, but I'll be sure to let them know about both options.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Twitter-Timeline and migrated to [EE Twitter by Click Rain](https://github.com/click-rain/EE_Twitter/), it was quick and easy and worked well. I had to make just a couple of template changes and i was off to the races.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/which-twitter-plugins-are-compatible-with-the-new-v1-1-api/7057#7057) has a whole list of Twitter plugins that will work with the new Twitter v1.1 API.